# Unable To Install Python Module -- Missing Vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, module

So I've checked out the question [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) and tried to set that `ENV` variable to all of the values suggested, however, for some reason when trying to install '`pymssql`', `vcvarsall.bat` is unable to be found? I have Visual Studio 2008 installed which is why this is so perplexing.

Any ideas?

Comment: The ideas I have are answers on the dupe link.

Comment: @MartijnPieters haha fair enough!

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18045219/355230) answer to the question you linked to in your answer?

Comment: @martineau I did not.

Answer (score 2):

From [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat):

> @VolodymyrB "You can install compiled version from
>   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/"

Worked for me!